# Issue when printing Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, printf, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list of 5 nodes and print them. I don't know why I cannot see the result when printing the linked list even though I do not get errors and I am sure my structure is fine. I only see blank screen. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <string.h> 


typedef struct msg *M;
struct msg{
    double id;
    M next;
};
M queue;

void new_msg(double id);
void printList();

void main()
{
    double r;

    srand(0);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        r = rand() % 100;
        new_msg(r);
    }

    printList(); // PRINT DOES NOT SHOW RESULTS :(
}

void printList()
{
    M temp;

    while (temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;

        printf("MSG ID:%6.3f \n", temp->id);
    } 
}

void new_msg(double id)
{
    M m;
    if(queue == NULL)
    {
        m = malloc(sizeof(struct msg));
    }
    else
    {
        m= queue;
        queue = queue->next; 
    }

    m->id = id;
    m->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: Oh right. Thank you. but still not showing the result :(

Comment: What? That was a _comment_, not an answer friend!!

Comment: You should try using debugger. There are several mistakes that would show up when you'd step through the code.

Comment: It is poor form to hide pointers behind typedefs.  Don't do it.  It confuses everybody, probably even you.

Comment: http://ideone.com/SoEoJG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both functions are invalid and have undefined behaviour at least because in the both functions there is an attempt to write to or read from a non-allocated memory.

Try the following

```
void printList()
{
    for ( M temp = queue; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next; )
    {
        printf("MSG ID:%6.3f \n", temp->id);
    } 
}


void new_msg(double id)
{
    M m = malloc( sizeof( struct msg ) );

    if ( m != NULL)
    {
        m->id = id;
        m->next = queue;
        queue = m; 
    }
}
```

Take into account that though some compilers allow to use the main declaration with the return type void nevertheless such a declaration is not C compliant.

You should write

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, inside `new_msg()` function, you define a local variable `m`, which is never *stored* and the global `queue` never gets updated. In every call, `queue` gets equal to NULL.

Next, in your `printList()` function,

1. `temp` is unitialized
2. `while (temp->next != NULL)` is likely to evaluate to false in very first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `new_msg` is correct, you are printing a list of pointers into nothingness, probably resulting in a core dump.

Your `M temp;` is not initialized. You probably want:

```
M temp = queue;
```